# Пытался сделать Конвертер температур из единиц Фаренгейта в единицы Цельсия на Rust

Tags: rust

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut celsius = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut celsius)
        .expect("Falied to read line");
    let farenheit = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
}
```

Выдает ошибку: cannot multiply `{integer}` to `std::string::String`

Comment: Хочется узнать, вы понимаете, как переводится текст ошибки? И в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Да понимаю, просто не понимаю как сделать это все в String.

Comment: Надо не это все в String, а celsius в integer? Не находите? Погуглите, пожалуйста, про преобразование строки в число в rust и все должно заработать.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Полный доработанный код ниже, использующий функции `str::parse::<T>()` ([документация](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse)) и `str::trim()` ([документация](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim)):

[Попробуй онлайн!](https://tio.run/##TY9BbsJADEX3OYWbBZpAlaIgFgzQZS/AAdCImGJp4kQzjqiEOHvwUETilS3//74d@ijD0EeEKLW11G6z7MzQOGJTwC0DLY8CTS9wQh@pj7CHgwTiX2sZr6bYPkXUWquIZHvOqcqArj56YjSzCWAiwL8OT2LyH@cJa5AWkgWSJX@BUzqP0a@u1AsaU5SdCxGt3dGq@tZx5JFXXtrqoUAsU9zZBeQLkijPvNlz2MAXrAtYwKr6F3f6pnj@MPntnn@OPmXdh6FaPgA)

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut celsius = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut celsius)
        .expect("Falied to read line");
    let ncelsius = celsius.trim().parse::<i32>().expect("Failed parsing int");
    let farenheit = (ncelsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
    println!("{}", farenheit);
}
```

Вход:

```
20
```

Выход:

```
68
```